# Rename-ing some woocommerce fields

Tags: wordpress, code-snippets

I have been having some hard times trying to configure my website.
I have been looking left and right on the internet for how can i rename certain fields on my webpage. I came to a point were i dint find any more snippets that i can use. If someone is kind enough to hekp me with the snippets for the bellow problems i would be extremly grateful :D

1) Login/ Registration form 
i have renamed the Login and regitration form, but i cant rename or completly remove the recover password button ( i tried 4-5 snippetes so far and non worked)

2) On my Account page i did some editing with the gettext snipped, but i wasn't able to translate the following word "Logout" and  "edit your password and account details"

3) i don't know how to translate the "search producs", the content of the box
4) i dont know how to rename the "apply coupon" button and the content of the box. For this one i used some snippets, but nothing happened :(
bellow, you can see my  website
http://www.toner.eurofinconsulting.ro/wp/

Answer (score 0):

Making adjustments like you have referenced are fairly simple to do in Woocommerce. Having said that, one of the first things to understand is how to correctly make changes to Woo template files. The easiest thing to do is to copy the **entire** directory `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates` to the root of your theme in a directory named `YOUR_THEME/woocommerce`. This now allows you to adjust any of the templates without touching files in the plugin directory (which you should NEVER do) while retaining the ability to update Woocommerce as updates are available.

Now, to make your changes:

1. Login/registration form - All changes you need can now be made in `wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/woocommerce/my-account/form-login.php`
2. Changes for this can be made in `wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/woocommerce/my-account/my-account.php`.
3. Changes to the search form - If this is using the Woocommerce search form, try making your changes in `wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/woocommerce/product-searchform.php`. If it is not there then try finding the search template used by your Wordpress theme.